# groovy Simple Template Engine Size too large

Tags: grails, groovy

Just a quick question. Can I run grails 2.3.5 with a newer groovy version?

It looks as if my groovy version does not have a

```
groovy.text.SteamingTemplateEngine
```

currently I am using

```
groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
```

But I am hitting the size limit of the SimpleTemplateEngine and I am looking for a workaround.

This is the error I am getting:

```
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:44)
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.LoggingListenerAdapter.onMessage(LoggingListenerAdapter.groovy:48)
    at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.onMessage(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed:
SimpleTemplateScript7.groovy: 1: String too long. The given string is 575915 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed.
 @ line 1, column 11.
```

If anybody has a proposition for a workaround, that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most updated version of groovy can be used using Grails 2.3.5 is the Groovy 2.1.9

Please see the related [link](https://gist.github.com/ishults/82a68897d85122562f65).

The [Template Engine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html) exists since Groovy 2.4.8

You should think of upgrading your Grails version. If you do so, read the **What's new in Grails X.X**  to make sure you are not breaking the current behavior of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately upgrading is not priority at the moment. So I need to look for a workaround. Like using handlebars.java instead! Anybody experience with that?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before (and answered too). The "workaround" is to add a comment in the GSP to break up the script block size like this:

```
<% 
  // just a comment 
%>
```